# Login page with different css and js files

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to angularjs and just started working on a project
I'm using ui.router for managing different views
the problem im facing is that i have a master page index.html for example

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="leadsangularApp">
<head>
    <link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div ui-view=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

all my views load in 
`<div ui-view=""></div>`
but what if i have a login page that has completely different css styles(head) and js files(footer) i need it to load inside different template, example

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="leadsangularApp">
<head>
    <link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div ui-view=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

if i try to do it with nested ui-view

```
 app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
          // States
          $stateProvider
            .state('root', {
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'views/default.html',
            })
            .state('home', {
                parent: "root",
                url: "/home",
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            })
            .state('login', { 
                url: "/login",
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            });
  });
```

my /login page has different view but still it loads the same css and js files
i want my /login page to have completely different head section and footer section, how do i achieve that?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking this is not a recommended approach, but there is a github project that does this for css: https://github.com/manuelmazzuola/angular-ui-router-styles. It's not something directly supported by ui-router.

Comment: thanks i wouldnt do that but my template has login page with different stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-href`. And depending on your needs, you will have to listen to `$stateChangeSuccess` and change the values that is binded to `ng-href`.

For your HTML, do something like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="{{stylesheet}}" />`

where the variable `stylesheet` is dynamically binded to your scope, and can change values according to your needs.

Then you can either listen to `$stateChangeStart` or `$stateChangeSuccess` and change the `$scope.stylesheet` values accordingly.

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  $scope.stylesheet = "style.css";

  $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

      if (toState.name === "login") {
        $scope.stylesheet = "style2.css"
      } else {
        $scope.stylesheet = "style.css"
      }
    })
})
```

Here is the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/qR7FLDAyRTkFndMQyWod?p=preview

To read more about ui-router's API: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state